# File opened by a script accessible by the user

Tags: php, file

I need to write a lot of data into a file while almost at the same time (at least at the time file is still opened by `fopen()`) user's browser needs to access it.

I found it's impossible until `fclose()` or end of the script.

Is there any way to make it possible?

Comment: What OS are we talking about? (although I bet I could guess)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its better to store the data in memory, or work with a temporary file. Then write to the master file at designated points rather then holding open the file for the entire execution of the script.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to send the file's mimetype to the user (`text/plain` for example), and `echo` the current file contents. After that you write both to the file and the output, so that the output to the user will mimic the file.